# Apache Hue and Solr Integration is only listing the cores in Hue dashboard

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, hue

The following is my problem. even if I configured and running the solr in cloud mode . Also using the SolrJ package I was able to list the collection (Not only the cores) . In Hue I was not able to get the collections.

It will give only the cores+shards+replica of each collection under Hue search dashboard. Because of this the reports created cores will have partial data .
How can I configure Hue.ini or anyother way which I can list the collections rather than the cores

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Web-UI-Hue-Beeswax/Connecting-to-Solrcloud-from-Hue/td-p/32110

is there is any way this feature will be available in Hue

Answer (score 0):

The related tracking jira is https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-5304. It should come up in Hue pretty soon.

Comment: Thanks Romian . This is useful